# How do you make an image disappear when a user clicks on it

Tags: html, css, image, click, tumblr

Hello Stackoverflowers,

So this is pretty much what I want to achieve (I apologize in advance for my explanation as I am not too familiar with the language of code)

1. A user visits my page on Tumblr.
2. The user sees an image of instructions hovering over the blog content with slight opacity.
3. Once the user reads the instructions, the image will disappear when the user clicks on the image.
4. The user explores the page.

I'm wondering -- Can this be done, even on Tumblr?

Any suggestions will be appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: Do you need the whole code written or do you have it partly done?

Answer (score 1):

Never used tumblr but you can add custom code using this guide :

http://www.chrisabraham.com/2011/04/06/how-to-add-custom-html-javascript-etc-code-to-your-tumblr/

And add this code in your `body` tag but change `"img.png"` to your image source

```
<img src="img.png" onclick="this.style.display='none';" style="position:absolute;opacity:0.5;left:50%;top:50%;width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:25px;margin-top:25px;z-index:100;"/>
```

The following is a working example :

http://jsfiddle.net/BRXVX/1

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But for some reason my posts hover over the image so I can't click on it... Is there any way I can force it to hover over everything?

Comment: I altered the code to include `z-index` see how that works out for you